# In a fixed effects regression model, can we estimate the fixed effects consistently if we let the number of observed units tend to infinity?

Tags: regression, panel-data, econometrics, fixed-effects-model

In a fixed effect regression model,$$Y_{it}=\alpha_i+u_{it},$$ where $1 \le i \le n$ and $1 \le t \le T$, we let $n \rightarrow \infty$, but keep $T$ fixed.

Are the fixed effects, $\alpha_i$, consistently estimated?

Comment: I think you need to distinguish between the model and the method used to estimate it. You can estimate the FE model with i-dummies, by differencing, or the within/demeaning method.

Answer (score 2):

> Are the fixed effects, $\alpha_i$, consistently estimated?

***No.*** Think about it: each time you add one more observation you also add one more parameter to estimate. So adding more cross-sectional observations $N$ does not add any more information for the consistency of an estimator for $\alpha_i$ (for instance, the usual dummy estimate).